# Understand the dictionary parts (integers to string in python)

Tags: python, pandas

As I am fond of python in the last period, I started to read articles and watched videos to know the basics.
At this member @jezrael link https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael, I found this code

```
import pandas as pd

d = {0: {50: 16, 23: 7, 22: 7, 5: 1, 31: 10, 47: 15, 2: 0, 44: 14, 39: 13, 21: 7, 11: 3, 30: 10, 16: 5, 42: 14, 26: 8, 1: 0, 40: 13, 32: 10, 34: 11, 46: 15, 49: 16, 15: 5, 37: 12, 9: 3, 12: 4, 41: 13, 24: 8, 10: 3, 18: 6, 8: 2, 33: 11, 35: 11, 0: 0, 36: 12, 27: 9, 48: 16, 38: 12, 7: 2, 28: 9, 3: 1, 29: 9, 43: 14, 4: 1, 45: 15, 17: 5, 14: 4, 13: 4, 19: 6, 25: 8, 20: 6, 6: 2}, 1: {50: 2, 23: 2, 22: 1, 5: 2, 31: 1, 47: 2, 2: 2, 44: 2, 39: 0, 21: 0, 11: 2, 30: 0, 16: 1, 42: 0, 26: 2, 1: 1, 40: 1, 32: 2, 34: 1, 46: 1, 49: 1, 15: 0, 37: 1, 9: 0, 12: 0, 41: 2, 24: 0, 10: 1, 18: 0, 8: 2, 33: 0, 35: 2, 0: 0, 36: 0, 27: 0, 48: 0, 38: 2, 7: 1, 28: 1, 3: 0, 29: 2, 43: 1, 4: 1, 45: 0, 17: 2, 14: 2, 13: 1, 19: 1, 25: 1, 20: 2, 6: 0}, 2: {50: 32, 23: 32, 22: 32, 5: 32, 31: 32, 47: 32, 2: 32, 44: 33, 39: 46, 21: 64, 11: 97, 30: 97, 16: 97, 42: 99, 26: 99, 1: 99, 40: 99, 32: 100, 34: 100, 46: 100, 49: 101, 15: 101, 37: 101, 9: 101, 12: 102, 41: 103, 24: 103, 10: 103, 18: 103, 8: 104, 33: 105, 35: 105, 0: 106, 36: 108, 27: 109, 48: 109, 38: 110, 7: 110, 28: 111, 3: 111, 29: 111, 43: 111, 4: 111, 45: 111, 17: 112, 14: 112, 13: 114, 19: 116, 25: 116, 20: 121, 6: 122}}
print (pd.DataFrame(d).pivot(0,1,2).applymap(chr).agg(''.join))
```

I tried to get the code but it seems it is beyond my mind at this moment. Can you help me with putting links to tutorials that enables me to get this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the first step is `pivot`, then change the number back to character , since every character have number behind it , then just do row `join`

```
pd.DataFrame(d).pivot(0,1,2).applymap(chr).agg('.'.join)
Out[30]: 
1
0    j.o.z.e.f.e.g.@.g.m.a.i.l...c.o.m
1    c.o.n.g.r.a.t. .t.o. .d.e.c.o.d.e
2     . .h.a.p.p.y. .c.o.d.i.n.g.!. .
```

---

`chr` map

```
chr(65)
Out[32]: 'A'
```