# How to append a longer list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna append a longer list to dataframe .But get an error ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (3)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['1', '2', '3']})

df['Data2'] =['1', '2', '3', '4']

print(df)
```

How can I fix it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add new rows by maximal length by new list or original DataFrame, if length of list should be changed, sometimes same length or sometimes length is shorter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['1', '2', '3']})

L = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

df = df.reindex(range(max(len(df), len(L))))
df['Data2'] = L
print (df)
  Data Data2
0    1     1
1    2     2
2    3     3
3  NaN     4
```

If always is length of list longer:

```
df = df.reindex(range(len(L)))
df['Data2'] = L
```

Comment: Tks , dude . Fixed

Comment: @jezrael Can you please have a look at this (taken from your profile's) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612348/?

Comment: How to replace Nan with Empty?

Comment: @YasserKhalil - Super ;) It is code with only onde idea - Many people contact me and ask me for many question for C, C++, Android, Java... So I want to avoid it and only if possible python/pandas  problems ;) For replace `NaN` to empty string use `df = df.fillna('')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) here but convert your list to a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) then use `pd.concat`

```
l = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
pd.concat([df, pd.Series(l, name='Data2')], axis=1)

  Data Data2
0    1     1
1    2     2
2    3     3
3  NaN     4
```